# How can I solve "decode string problem" using string manipulation?

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm, stack

I came across `Decode string problem` which is given an encoded string s, decode it With rule:
`N[encoded] => encoded*N`.

**Examples*:*

```php
$input = "4[abc]";
// output: abcabcabcabc

$input = "ac3[ab]d";
// output: acabababd

$input = "a2[b3[cd]]";
// output: abcdcdcdbcdcdcd
```

I have tried solving it, using string manipulation with if conditions, It works only for two inputs, However it fails at last one when the given input has multiple encoded string.

```php
$output = '';
$arr = str_split($input);
for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
    $char = $arr[$i];//current character
    if($char == '['){
        $closed = strpos($input, ']');
        $len = $closed - ($i+1);
        $output .= str_repeat(substr($input, $i+1, $len), $prev);
        $i = strpos($input, ']');
    }elseif(ctype_digit($char)){
        $prev = $char;
    }else{
        $output .= $char;
    }
}
echo $output;
```

Is there any ways to solving it using this approach or another. Or only can be solved using stack?
Thank you for any idea can help solving this problem!

Comment: Just curious - what's wrong with the stack approach? It seems to be more intuitive and nature in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve nested [], you have to decode from the inside out. The solution uses preg_replace_callback until there is nothing left to replace.

```
function fkdecode($str){
  while(true){
  $newStr = preg_replace_callback('~(\d+)\[([^\[\]]+)\]~',
    function($m){
      return str_repeat($m[2],(int)$m[1]);
    },
    $str);
   if($newStr == $str) break;
   $str = $newStr;
  }
  return $str;
}

//test
$inputs = ["4[abc]", // output: abcabcabcabc
 "ac3[ab]d", // output: acabababd
 "a2[b3[cd]]", // output: abcdcdcdbcdcdcd
];

foreach($inputs as $input){
  echo $input.' := '. fkdecode($input)."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
4[abc] := abcabcabcabc
ac3[ab]d := acabababd
a2[b3[cd]] := abcdcdcdbcdcdcd
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with offset (`$i` in your case) specified to decode multiple encoded string.

You could've used strlen instead of count. It's to avoid array to string conversion error. Also, you should take into consideration the case when `N` > 9.

```
$output = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) { 
    $char = $input[$i];//current character
    if($char == '['){
        $closed = strpos($input, ']', $i);
        $len = $closed - ($i+1);
        $output .= str_repeat(substr($input, $i+1, $len), $prev);
        $i = strpos($input, ']', $i);
    }elseif(ctype_digit($char)){
        $end = strpos($input, '[', $i);
        $len = $end - $i;
        $prev = substr($input, $i, $len);
        $i = strpos($input, '[', $i) - 1;
    }else{
        $output .= $char;
    }
}

echo $output;
?>
```

BTW, this doesn't solve the nested `[]`. You could use a stack to solve it. **Hint:** Check if there's a `[` before `$closed`. [Or use this non-O(n) approach.](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/discuss/1211807/C%2B%2B-Oms-Time-with-explanation)